# useFormik doesn't allow me to set null initialValues even when using a validationSchema

Tags: typescript, formik

I'm using the `useFormik` hook for my form. The `userId` is a `select`, so initially its value is `null`, however my `validationSchema` makes this a required field before being able to submit the form.

```
  const formik = useFormik<ApiCreditDebitCreateInput>({
    initialValues: {
      userId: null, // TS warning: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts
    },
    validationSchema: schema,
    onSubmit,
  });
```

However, I'm getting the following Typescript warning in `userId: null`:

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this since `null` is a valid "initial" value for `userId`, but won't ever be allowed to be submitted because of my schema.

Keeping this schema simplifies my `onSubmit` code since I won't have to check for null values there.

Thanks!

Comment: You must add nullable() for userId in your `validationSchema` file.
ex: userId: Yup.string().nullable()

Comment: Yes I know making it nullable in the schema will fix this, but I don't want to have to do null checks in `onSubmit`. Thats the whole point of using a validation schema.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this by setting the initial value of `userId` to `""`, and not validating that it is defined but also its length in the `validationSchema`.

```
  const formik = useFormik<ApiCreditDebitCreateInput>({
    initialValues: {
      userId: ``,
    },
    validationSchema: schema,
    onSubmit,
  });
```

Comment: Can you post your `validationSchema`?